# wdio Allure report - failed tests showing as 'unknown'

Tags: javascript, report, allure, wdio

I have a bog standard Allure setup running with webdriver.io, and I'm able to generate reports fine. However, all the test runs which fail are marked as 'Unknown' within the report itself, which a) is not the correct status and b) seems to not allow screenshots to be added to the report.

Do I have to configure Allure to handle failures in any way? I'm running tests across multiple browsers/platforms, so the test names are the same for each device being tested. I have tried to randomise the name by appending a random string to the test name, but the same thing happens.

[image: report view]

Allure config is as follows:

```
['allure', {
      outputDir: 'allure-results',
      disableWebdriverStepsReporting: false,
      disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: false,
    }]
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By changing outputDir, I got the correct report.

```
['allure', {
        outputDir: 'reports',
        disableWebdriverStepsReporting: false,
        disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: false,
}]
```

for this you have to use cmd -

```
allure generate reports --clean && allure open
```